# Too quick with the "close hammer"?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, closed-questions

A couple of the questions that I've asked have attracted close votes - I think unfairly:

<strike>Most recently, [I asked a question about Tomcat been very slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5222445/java-tomcat-slow-serving-static-files) at certain times to serve some static files. Because at first glance this skirts near to the "Apache HTTPD Vs. Tomcat HTTP Throughput Debate" it got a close vote and someone telling me the question "had already been discussed". My issue was occaisionally a small (<2 KiB) file may take 90+ seconds to start downloading. Even if it were related, where's the explanation of what's happening?</strike>

**Edit:** Fairly moved to Serverfault. Would be nice if there was a notification of the close reason, but I understand this may already be happening?

---

One [question I asked got closed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4897428/java-why-multiple-interfaces-instead-of-multiple-inheritence) - this time because it got pounced on because it was assumed I was asking why Java didn't support multiple-inheritence. I wasn't (I understand the diamond problem etc etc). Instead, the actual question gets completely ignored. :(

**Edit:** This one is still an issue for me. I'm trying to ask why inheriting from multiple interfaces is seen as the solution to multiple inheritence. As stated in my comments, the method may guarantee a given return type, but it doesn't guarantee the same process / calculation 'under the covers'. The linked questions don't answer that.

It seems many mods/users who can cast close votes are a bit 'trigger happy'. It seems that many don't read the question they want to close - or attempt to help the user explain or expand on their question.

I understand that many questions get asked over and over, but I'd like to find a why to encourage a more 'helpful' approach than just closing questions sometimes. Any ideas, comments or suggestions?

Comment: @Mikaveli, can you provide a link to the question(s).

Comment: @Barry: Thank you for adding the links.

Comment: The first question had two off-topic close votes (now three, one from me) because it belongs on Server fault. The comment pointing out the related question is completely unrelated to the close vote, and a friendly gesture to help you find a quicker solution... But if it's impossible to see the close reason, that is admittedly hard to tell.

Comment: The second I can't judge on because I don't speak Java. Are the duplicates pointed out not answering your question?

Comment: @Pekka: The second question got half-answered (after being closed). Because an interface provides a formal relationship regarding return types etc, most posters see that as the same functionality. But just because two methods inheriting from the same interface provide "number in, number out" it doesn't mean they're doing the exact same calculation.

Comment: @Mikaveli right. You *could* rephrase and ask again - if you have a point, make it clearly, mention the previous question, and link to Meta discussion, you're likely to get support if it gets closevotes again.

Comment: You shoot yourself in the leg by giving two examples which do deserve closing/migrating. Your first question got nothing to do with programming for example, that's why it doesn't belong to Stack Overflow. There is no badge and no reputation gained from closing questions, we are doing it to keep SO clean and organized as it should be. To avoid having your questions closed simply take some time before posting to think where it belong and see if it was already asked before. Simple as that. :)

Comment: @Shadow well, he can't see what the close vote is for - migration or something else. That is arguably a flaw in the system

Comment: @Pekka didn't know that.. probably will be good idea to suggest feature request to show this information?

Comment: @Shadow yup - although I think it has been done already IIRC

Comment: @Shadow: The Tomcat question being migrated is understandable - now that I know what has / was happening. As for the Java interface question - I still don't see an answer to my question?

Comment: @Mik not sure what you mean by "don't see answer" for the Java question - it was closed because it was already asked before. If you want it re-opened the quickest way will be to flag it for mod attention explaining why, as I'm not familiar enough with Java I can't really know. You can also notify all 5 "closers" by posting 5 comments starting with @Jigar, @Péter, @Peter, @Sean and @Mart and asking them to reopen.

Comment: @Shadow: That's my point - it wasn't asked before. It's very close to a commonly asked question, but that wasn't what I asked. I looked at the linked questions, they only answer "Why no multiple inheritence?".

Comment: @Mik following your edit, I now partially agree - it's possible that sometimes people don't give enough attention before closing question *as duplicate* and this results in unfair closing. Personally I double check the duplicate I find is really the same, but mistakes *can* happen. The above suggestion of notifying the people who closed the question will solve such cases, if you can convince them why your question is not exact duplicate..

Comment: @Shadow: That seems logical. My only reservation is that reopening the question may result in more "hammering". Adding that question on here got the original downvoted today... I'm not sure how to reprhase it clearly enough to avoid the "asked before" flood.

Comment: @Mik you can start the question by "In addition to [url here], I have similar but somewhat different question..." this will most likely cause people to think twice before voting to close it.

Comment: @Shadow & @Pekka: Thank you for all your help. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your first question got a migration vote to SeverFault, not a close vote (and now a second one from me — this is a server configuration question, not a programming one).

Second one got closed because it asks the same thing as the earlier ones (which already have answers). If you really not asking about the same thing, you need to rephrase it.

Comment: I understand that the second question probably needed rephrasing, but once it got closed (quickly) there seemed litle point (and I really didn't fancy my chances with a rephrased repost).

Comment: @Mikaveli, you don't lose anything (except time) from having question closed, so the risk is relatively low.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe we can show the reason for the close before it's closed.  The first one is getting close votes because it's off-topic.  I also added a close vote to move it to serverfault, where it belongs.

The second one is an issue that has been discussed countless times before.  Your actual question is the exact one that has been discussed.  Multiple inheritance in Java is explained repeatedly.